# Nodejs multiple axios get requests return a Primise

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, axios

How to return a `Promise` from the multiple `axios` get requests?
I have below code.

```
async function main() {
    const URL_1 = 'abc.com/get1/data1';
    const result_1 = await getData(URL_1);

    const URL_2 = 'abc.com/get2/data2';
    const result_2 = await getData(URL_2);
}

async function getData(dataURI) {
    let getURI = dataURI;
    
    const config = {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${my-token-text}`,
      },
    };
    
    var finalData = [];

    // until we get the next URL keep sending the requests 
    while (getURI != null) {
        try {
            const getResult = await axios.get(getURI, config);
            if (getResult.status === 200) {
                const receivedData = getResult.data.value;
                finalData.push(...receivedData);
                
                // check if we have nextLink in the payload
                if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(getResult.data, 'nextLink')) {
                    getURI = getResult.data.nextLink;
                } else {
                    getURI = null;
                    return finalData;
                }
            }
        } catch (err) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is:

```
async function main() {
    const URL_1 = 'abc.com/get1/data1';
    const result_1 = getData(URL_1);
    promisesArray.push(result_1);

    const URL_2 = 'abc.com/get2/data2';
    const result_2 = getData(URL_2);
    promisesArray.push(result_2);

    await Promise.allSettled(promisesArray).then((results) => {
        console.log('Promise All Done: ', results);
    });
}
```

This why I can perform all the requests in parallel.

But when I update the function `getData(dataURI)` to return `return new Promise` then I get error for `await axios`.

```
async function getData(dataURI) {
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // Same code as above 
 
   });
}
```

I get error:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

As `Promise` is not async I cannot await in the Promise.

Comment: "But when I update the function getData(dataURI) to return return new Promise then I get error for await axios." — Don't do that. That's for when you have a callback function that you need to convert to a promise. You already have promises.

Comment: The code you have (*before* the line "This why I can perform all the requests in parallel.") looks like it already does what you want (in parallel).

Comment: @Quentin Can you please explain bit more on this, I did the approach given in the answer and it is working as expected.

Comment: `async` functions return promises. HTTP requests are performed asynchronously.  `const result_1 = getData(URL_1);` assigns a promise to `result_1`. `const result_2 = getData(URL_2);` assigns a promise to `result_2`. The two sets of HTTP requests run in parallel. When both are finished the promise returned by `Promise.allSettled(promisesArray)` resolves.

Comment: In short, to get two calls to `getData` (the version that is in the first code block in this question) to run in parallel  you should use `Promise.allSettled` and not `await getData(...)` **which you already are doing**.

Comment: But I am not returning `new Promise` in the `getData` in the original code. If we are calling `Promise,allSettled`, we will need to return a Promise from the `getData` function right?

Comment: `async` functions always return promises **without** needing to use the `new Promise` constructor to create your own. You should only need to use `new Promise` when you have an old-style API that accepts a callback (which you don't).

Comment: Oh ok got it, so when it fails in `catch` will the Promise gets `rejected`? Can you explain on that part.

Comment: No. It gets rejected if the function throws an error. If you *catch* the error then it won't be rejected. (In your case, it hits `break` to break out of the `while` loop and then returns (a promise that resolves as) `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the details, I did update the code to `throw err` from the catch and I am getting `rejected` in `Promise.allSettled`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {

// Same code as above 

});
```

Comment: Wrapping the promise returned by the async function in another function is pointless complexity. Don't do this.

Comment: Because pointless complexity is bad. Pressing forward with the new of adding `new Promise` to the OP's code makes it worse. Bad advice needs downvotes.

Comment: @Quentin he obviously didn't know you could tag arrow function as async, this might be useful to him. Plus did you know that promises auto-unwrap?

Comment: "Plus did you know that promises auto-unwrap?" — I did, but pointlessly complex code is harder for developers to maintain and debug.

Comment: farewell, can't wait to see your answer

Comment: I'm not going to write an answer. I've voted to close the question as "not reproducible" because the OP doesn't have the problem they think they do.